# wpa_cli failing to connect to WPS enabled WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant, wpa2-psk, wps

I am trying to connect to a Netgear arlo basestation which communicates to it's network cameras via WiFi. The connection is done via WiFi Protected Setup (WPS). I can successfully connect a camera to another WPS bushbutton enabled AccessPoint and see the camera/portscan it.

Now I'd like to connect my notebook computer running debian to the arlo base station.

I have successfully connected to my usual Router via WPS, so "the thing itself" works (ie. a WPS bushbutton connection to my WPA2/CCMP WiFi can be established via `wpa_cli` and used thereafter).

This is `wpa_cli`'s output when trying to connect to the arlo base whose fixed, unchangeable and unmanageable SSID is `NETGEAR73`, bssid a0:63:91:xx:xx:xx (see the security concerns I have with this, leaving an unmanageable Accesspoint in my cosy home network?!):

```
> scan_results
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
a0:63:91:xx:xx:xx   2437    -66 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   NETGEAR73
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x1   2462    -57 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    my_wifi
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x2   2462    -59 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    my_wifi
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x3   2412    -44 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    my_wifi
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x4   2462    -66 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    my_wifi
> wps_pbc a0:63:91:xx:xx:xx
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
(...)
```

*(me hurrying downstairs to the arlo basestation, manually pushing the `SYNC`button three times to start the WPS bushbutton sequence)*

```
(...)
<3>Trying to associate with a0:63:91:xx:xx:xx (SSID='NETGEAR73' freq=2437 MHz)
<3>Association request to the driver failed
<3>Associated with a0:63:91:xx:xx:xx
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='started' parameter=''
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=14122 method=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='accept proposed method' parameter='WSC'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 14122 method 1 (WSC) selected
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='completion' parameter='failure'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
<3>WPS-FAIL
<3>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=a0:63:91:xx:xx:xx reason=3 locally_generated=1
>
```

For some reason my connection is rejected (the `<3>Association request to the driver failed`-part also happens to appear when I successfully connect to my own WiFi network) with the `<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed`-error.

I *did* indeed notice that my own router (see below) is listed as `[WPS-PBC]` whereas the arlo basestation is listed as `[WPS]`, which should indicate PIN mode. Sometimes (and I can not reproduce it) it *is* listed as `[WPS-PBC]`, yet the above sequence still fails exactly the same.

Any ideas what could be going on here and why I cannot WPS-connect (and, thus find it's WPA2-PSK) to the arlo AP?

---

Just for the fun of showing that it *actually does work* for other connections, this is me connecting to my own WiFi via WPS. `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:7a` is the router which can do WPS bushbutton, `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x1/x2/x3` are the other accesspoints which cannot, yet share the same SSID and WPA2-PSK with the router(funny sidenote: WPS goes through between notebook and router, yet the notebook usually connects to one of the accesspoints which is a little closer to it after WPS succeeded):

```
me@notebook:~# /sbin/wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.1
(...)
Selected interface 'wlan0'

Interactive mode

> scan_results
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:7a   2412    -38 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS-PBC][ESS]   my_wifi
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x1   2462    -58 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    my_wifi
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x2   2462    -63 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    my_wifi
a0:63:91:xx:xx:xx   2437    -69 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   NETGEAR73
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x3   2462    -70 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    my_wifi
> wps_pbc xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:7a
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE-PBC
<3>Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:7a (SSID='my_wifi' freq=2412 MHz)
<3>Association request to the driver failed
<3>Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:7a
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='started' parameter=''
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=14122 method=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='accept proposed method' parameter='WSC'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 14122 method 1 (WSC) selected
<3>WPS-CRED-RECEIVED
<3>WPS-SUCCESS
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='completion' parameter='failure'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
<3>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:7a reason=3 locally_generated=1
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>Trying to associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x2 (SSID='my_wifi' freq=2462 MHz)
<3>Association request to the driver failed
<3>Associated with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x2
<3>WPA: Key negotiation completed with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x2 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
<3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x2 completed [id=0 id_str=]
> quit
me@notebook:~# /sbin/iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"my_wifi"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x2
          Bit Rate=5.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

me@notebook:~# /sbin/dhclient -v wlan0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
(...)
Listening on LPF/wlan0/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:8b
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:8b
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x6fb7b800)
DHCPREQUEST of some.ip on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6fb7b800)
DHCPOFFER of some.ip from router.ip
DHCPACK of some.ip from router.ip
bound to some.ip -- renewal in 408095 seconds.
me@notebook:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=13.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=11.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=12.2 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.680/12.469/13.442/0.736 ms
me@notebook:~#
```

So - yes, it does work under other circumstances.